# Access client side state in getServerSideProps in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

My all api requests are in getServerSideProps. My every api request has a param of user location, which i get using the ip address of a user and then i store it to global state using redux. But when i navigate to some another page i want to access that location on nextjs server.  Is there any way to access that state ?

Example:
User comes to webiste on "/homepage" route and react renders homepage and sets the location in global state.
But when user navigates to "/products" routes, products api will be called in nextjs server in "getServerSideProps". Is there any way to access that location state there ?

Comment: It's a one-way communication only, meaning you can initialise the Redux store from inside `getServerSideProps`, but you cannot access data that was put there from the client-side. How do you get the IP address that you store in the global state? Can you not retrieve it the same way inside `getServerSideProps`?

Comment: I fetch ip address from the req context .Thanks for clarification, i was thinking i was missing something here. But there should be some way for communication. What do you think @juliomalves ?

Comment: The `req` object is available from `getServerSideProps` context. See https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering.

Comment: yes i am using it but issue is if there is some data loades on one route and stored in global store and somehow i want data available to serversideprops then there will be issue you know you wanna share the userId or userRole or some other info. My all api calls are in serverSideProps . So i need to load some data on every call.

Comment: You might want to consider loading user-related data on the client-side instead. You can potentially also store the data in cookies, as that's also available inside `getServerSideProps`.

Comment: Then whats the use of SSR if i load all data on client side ?

Comment: SSR is useful to pre-render content that is the same for every user. If your app depends heavily on user-related data, then maybe SSR isn't the right fit?

Comment: Yes, i should move to client side.